# Showing snackbar without a view reference, but application context

Tags: android, android-context, applicationcontext, observers, android-snackbar

I'm writing an android library, used by other android apps [supporting API 14 and above].

I want to show a snackbar

```
public final class MySnackbar
    extends BaseTransientBottomBar
```

As a library, my business object registers an event notification (account changing). In the callback body I don't have any UI object reference, but application context.

How can I get the window or any root view to send to the snackbar.

Or I have to get the root view from the hosting activity?

I know I can maintain `currentActivity` reference, but it might be too dramatic change for my code for now.

I have tried this, but it's for API 21 and above:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
```

Comment: Undoable since `Snackbar` must be a child of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @Pawel only for animations, snackbar will work with any `ViewGroup` but animation won't show if the `parent` ain't `DrawerLayout` or `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @DarShan thanks for that, but that holds for `BaseTransientBottomBar` base class as well?